# add more conditions for query builder in ManyToMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

i have relationships (ManyToMany) in symfony2:

Item <-> Category

Database:

Item:
ID NAME

Category
ID NAME SLUG

Item Category:
id item_id category_id

I'm trying to find all the items that are connected with the categories by x slugs.

code does not work:

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i, c ')
        ->leftJoin('i.categories', 'c')

        ->setParameter('firstSlug', 'first')
        ->andWhere('c.slug = :firstSlug')

        ->setParameter('secondSlug', 'second')
        ->andWhere('c.slug = :secondSlug')
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: I think `setParameter` needs to come after the `andWhere` clauses

Comment: this code: 

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i, c ')
        ->leftJoin('i.categories', 'c')

        ->setParameter('firstSlug', 'first')
        ->andWhere('c.slug = :firstSlug')

retrieve item id : 1

Comment: this code:

    ->setParameter('secondSlug', 'second')
        ->andWhere('c.slug = :secondSlug')

retrive item id : 1 

but I need to pull out items that are here and here (by category slug)

Comment: if i use:

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i, c ')
        ->leftJoin('i.categories', 'c')

        ->setParameter('firstSlug', 'first')
        ->andWhere('c.slug = :firstSlug')

        ->setParameter('secondSlug', 'second')
        ->andWhere('c.slug = :secondSlug')

query returns nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb
    ->select('i')
    ->join('i.categories', 'c')
    ->where($qb->expr()->in('c.slug', ':slugs'))
    ->setParameter('slugs', ['first_slug', 'second_slug', 'third_slug'])
    ->distinct(i.id) // to prevent having same item more than once
;
```

Comment: This is the same as ->setParameter('firstSlug', 'first')
    ->andWhere('c.slug = :firstSlug')

    ->setParameter('secondSlug', 'second')
    ->orWhere('c.slug = :secondSlug')  i need return items that are in both categories with a given list of slugs

Comment: best uncheck the answer then, or noone else will likely respond.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a double and, and none of your categories have two slugs, so no categories match both c.slug=first and c.slug=second.  Try:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
    ->select('i, c ')
    ->leftJoin('i.categories', 'c')

    ->setParameter('firstSlug', 'first')
    ->andWhere('c.slug = :firstSlug')

    ->setParameter('secondSlug', 'second')
    ->orWhere('c.slug = :secondSlug')                <<< change in this line
```

Comment: I need return items that are in both categories with a given list of slugs, not OR.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, I think you want to use join conditions:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->select('i, c ')
   ->join('i.categories', 'c', 'ON', 'c.slug = :firstSlug')
   ->join('i.categories', 'c', 'ON', 'c.slug = :secondSlug')
   ->setParameter('firstSlug', 'first')
   ->andWhere('c.slug = :secondSlug')
;
```

You cannot use left joins, you'll match items that don't have your slugs.